# How to Calculate current Sales Price of item from Code (after evaluating all trade agreements and discount offers)

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to develop a SSRS report which will list all items and their sales prices, some items have discount offers, some have trade agreements and some items have both applied on them, I am wondering if there is a built-in method which will return current sales price after taking all offers and trade agreements into account.

any code example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Waiting for any kind of help.....

Answer (score 2):

The logic for finding trade agreements is contained in class `PriceDisc`. It also has a fallback if no agreements exist.

On table `InventTable` there's a method `salesPriceAgreement()` which uses that class and might do just what you need or at least serve as an example of how to use the class.